# Enabling Kerberos for Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, kerberos, spn

I am trying to enable Kerberos for MS SQL Server Reporting Services. I am fairly familiar with Windows security and how it works. However, I am new to Scale Out Deployment and Clustering of Windows Servers. I know I need to add SPNs that direct towards both SSRS web service (using a domain account) and to the database engine. I am a little confused on exactly how the SPNs should be structured. I have looked in Stack Overflow and other resources and most reference a standard deployment without scale-out/clustering.

My questions are:

- Do I structure the SPNs to point to the node, the cluster, both?
- How do I structure the SPNs for each?
- Do I need to include ports?

I ran the Microsoft Kerberos Configuration Manager and the Reporting Services SPN shows "Unauthorized". I don't know what this means and I can't find documentation on the tool.

[image: Kerberos Tool Result]

Here are the details of my setup:

**Domain:** clearwd (not my actual domain)

**Server OS:** Windows Server 2016

**Cluster:** DEV-CLUSTER

**Node 1:** DEV-SQL1

**Node 2:** DEV-SQL2

**Role:** DEV-CLUSTER1 (SQL Server / MSSQLSERVER)

**SQL Server Version:** 2016 Enterprise

**SQL Server Name:** DEV-CLUSTER1

**SQL Server Port:** 1433

**SSRS Service Account:** ssrsuser.clearwd.com OR clearwd\ssrsuser

**SSRS Mode:** Native

**SSRS Report Server Web Service URL:** http://DEV-SQL01:80/ReportServer

**SSRS Web Portal URL:** http://DEV-SQL01:80/Reports

Let me know if any other information is needed.

References:

https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/implement-kerberos-delegation-ssrs-0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/register-a-service-principal-name-spn-for-a-report-server?view=sql-server-2017

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/configure-report-server-urls-ssrs-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-2017